# Failed to lock refs/heads/master

Tags: git

I am relatively new to git and am facing this problem. The git push command shows the error below. I will explain to you from the beginning what I had been trying to do.
I created a submodule, committed, and pushed it. The push throws the error below.

```
Salman@PC_HOME ~/git/breakit-web-app (master)
$ git push origin master
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 421 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: bb/acl: salmanmanekia is allowed. accepted payload.
error: Ref refs/heads/master is at 6a47a0fd398610a75bdab8976f842dc0efd89f86 but expected 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
remote: error: failed to lock refs/heads/master

To ssh://git@bitbucket.org/majuri/breakit-web-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to lock)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/majuri/breakit-web-app.git'
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

After that, I tried some solutions, but none of them worked. I will also explain briefly what I have been trying.

1: From the bitbucket repo, I noticed there are some dangling commits (the red arrow in picture 2), so I gave the following commands to solve that
git gc and git prune.

2: I also tried commands like git revert HEAD and git push origin HEAD --force, but none seem to work.
[image]

Other details:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master
refs/heads/master

$ git rev-parse master
0da090c5cbde10ff19602a2722ae05231c30dff5

$ git show-ref master
0da090c5cbde10ff19602a2722ae05231c30dff5 refs/heads/master
6a47a0fd398610a75bdab8976f842dc0efd89f86 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the output from `git show-ref refs/remotes/origin/master`?

Comment: $ git show-ref refs/remotes/origin/master
6a47a0fd398610a75bdab8976f842dc0efd89f86 refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: What does `git fetch origin` output?  Maybe your remote tracking branches got out-of-sync or something...?

Comment: It outputs nothing...

Salman@PC_HOME ~/git/breakit-web-app (master)
$ git fetch origin

Comment: What is the output of `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master`, `git rev-parse master`, and `git show-ref master`?

Comment: Salman@PC_HOME ~/git/breakit-web-app (dev270612)
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master    
refs/heads/master

Comment: Salman@PC_HOME ~/git/breakit-web-app (dev270612)
$ git rev-parse master      
0da090c5cbde10ff19602a2722ae05231c30dff5

Comment: Salman@PC_HOME ~/git/breakit-web-app (dev270612)
$ git show-ref master       
0da090c5cbde10ff19602a2722ae05231c30dff5 refs/heads/master      
6a47a0fd398610a75bdab8976f842dc0efd89f86 refs/remotes/origin/master

Comment: what about `git cat-file -t 6a47a0fd3`, `git branch -a --contains 6a47a0fd3`, and `git ls-remote origin master`?  (Please edit the question and put the information there rather than in comments.)

Comment: I have forced push to my old version in the master from where the tracking branch was going out of sync.

Answer (score 35):

You have to update the HEAD known by git. It will be transparent for you.

1. Go to `master` branch

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. Get updates from the remote to your local repository

   ```
   git fetch
   ```
3. Update your local repository using rebase instead of merge. See [there difference between `git pull` and `git rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37724516/2394026)

   ```
   git rebase origin/master
   ```
4. Push your `master` branch

   ```
   git push origin master:master
   ```

Comment: This worked for me ( using sourcetree ). Simple but efficient.

Comment: you can use a simpler `git pull origin master --rebase` that is the same as your first 3 command

Answer (score 4):

If you tried all these above steps and did not work, try the following command.

```
rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"
```

Answer (score 2):

git pull origin master --rebase

this worked for me