# Unmerged Commits going off the track with no future

Tags: git

I am new to git and trying to grasp the ins and outs of it. I have one efficiency related question. In the picture below please see the red arrow.

[image]

My question is what can this scenario be named i mean the line associated with the red arrow that has no future. Also what are the different color lines technicaly termed as. I am understanding the concept of it but its just that i wanted to google my this problem but due to my limited git vocabulary i wasnt able to search anything meaning ful. After tellinng me the names of these two.

My next and important question is that should these red arrow lines be considered as problem ?. If yes, then why and how to reolve those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't native Git; you're using some sort of GUI tool. I won't even try to guess, and from a practical point of view it probably doesn't matter as long as it's something sensible.

The colored lines are branches. The dots on each line represent commits. Whether or not the colors mean anything specific, other than a way to differentiate branches, is up to your GUI.

The top-most dot of each line is a branch head. Your red arrow is pointing to a merge commit that was never merged back with the rest of your ongoing development--or vice-versa, depending on your point of view. It's informational, and not intrinsically good or bad; it doesn't matter to Git whether you ever merge your branches.

The black line will "move up" whenever you merge your other commits into that branch. Whether or not you *should* is not a Git issue.

Comment: Is there a way to delete those hanging ones. I think that those unmerged branches are causing me a problem i.e when i create a submoudle and add, commit and push it to the master then it creates the green line and throws error. see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228436/failed-to-lock-refs-heads-master . I am no way good in git but my intuation and a bit of research says that maybe these hanging uncommited merges can be the cause of problem.

Comment: This is verging on a separate question. I doubt it's your problem, but you can "undangle" them by merging to/from some other branch, or deleting the branch with `git branch -D <branch_name>`. If I were you, I'd talk to one of the other developers on your project before throwing away a branch, though.