# Does git pull always create a merge commit?

Tags: git

Does `git pull` always create a merge commit?

If I have a feature branch that I bring up to date with `git pull -r . master`, and then I switch to master and do `git pull . feature-branch` I don't *think* I get a merge commit.

Comment: `git pull` can fast-forward.

Comment: Okay so when it fast-forwards, it results in no merge commit? So I need to use the --no-ff flag to force a merge commit if I want one?

Comment: Yes, the description of the `-ff` (fast-forward) flag says: *"When the merge resolves as a fast-forward, only update the branch pointer, without creating a merge commit. This is the default behavior."*

Comment: Using the `--rebase` flag changes things a bit (I'm not sure about how it works tbh), but it still shouldn't create a merge commit by default I'd think. Don't take my word for it, though.

Comment: I would like to see an answer that compares different ways of doing `git pull` (default, `-no-ff`, `--rebase`, etc.).

Comment: @tuple_cat : I added the --rebase option in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a [good example about git merge and fast-forward](https://web.archive.org/web/20160629103328/http://ariya.ofilabs.com:80/2013/09/fast-forward-git-merge.html) on the linked website.

@MicroVirus gave a nice explanation. Below, the grey point is the HEAD of your local HEAD before the pull (fetch + merge). You can see the difference between the two way to merge.

[image: git fast forward]
<sub>(source: [ofilabs.com](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/merging.png))</sub>

Another way to update your repo with `git pull` is to use `--rebase` option. This option apply your commits on the top of the pulled branch rewriting the history. You can read [details there](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html).
People are divided between using `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`. To my mind, the rebase should be use for bug fix instead classic pull should be use when a new feature is merged to master.

**Git rebase example**
[image: git rebase example]

Read the link bellow to have an idea on differents point of view :

- [git pull VS git fetch + git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/git-pull-vs-git-fetch-git-rebase/3357174#3357174)
- [Difference between git pull and git pull --rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930527/difference-between-git-pull-and-git-pull-rebase/18930564#18930564)