# Flattening Simple Git History Commits

Tags: git

I've got a got commit history that looks like this:

[image]

As shown, a branch (blue) was created from master (red) and later merged back into master. The master branch had not changed at all.

Is it possible retroactively to flatten this loop into a linear sequence of 5 non-squashed commits?

I guess if the last merge commit was done as a `git rebase` of master that would have given me the linear sequence.

Comment: You can use `git rebase` or `git replace` to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

To keep a flat git history, you should use `rebase` instead of `merge` when you want to update branches. You could see an explanation of rebase versus merge in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37724516/2394026).

From your current state, if your `HEAD (master)` is the merge, you could do

- Clean your working dir (or stash changes)
- `git reset --hard LastCommit` , where `LastCommit` is the last commit from red branch which is not on the blue one.
- `git rebase blueBranch redBranch`

> [git-rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) - Reapply commits on top of another base tip

Comment: But presumably, `blueBranch` does not contain the final merge commit that merge it into `master`. That commit (i.e. the HEAD) is part of the `master`'s commits.

Comment: @AdiShavit That merge commit would not be needed when you do a rebase. Is that what you mean?

Comment: General warning, only rebase if your commits are all local. If you have already pushed those commits, rebase can lead to all kinds of problems.

Comment: Not necessarily. If it was fast-fwd, then it should automatically appear as a linear history. Although I suspect GitHub PRs always appear as actual commits even when fast-fwd was possible (making your comment about local changes even more relevant).

Comment: The last commit of `blueBranch` doesn't need to be a merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `git reset HEAD^2 --hard` is enough.