# error when pushing branch into github - 'remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': Unable to create'

Tags: git, version-control

I get the below exception when I try to push my local branch into master

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master': Unable to create '/data/c01/n08/p/vp0664/data/d-41/r-27032041/refs/heads/master.lock': File exists.
remote: 
remote: If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
remote: git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
remote: process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

- I get this exception only when pushing the master branch.
- I get this exception when pushing the master branch even from other computers.
- I get this exception even when I try to merge dev branch into master on bitbucket website directly not involving the local computer.

Because of the above 3 reasons I don't think it is a issue with my local .git folder. I can't think of what the possible cause is.

I have tried solutions available in answers to similar exceptions, but all of them are about cleaning/purging/manipulating the files in the .git folder but I get this same issue even from different computers and even on the bitbucket portal itself.

Please vote for the [issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/15209/error-when-pushing-branch-into-github), if you are hitting it as well.

PS: I am using the bitbucket.org cloud hosted option.

Comment: What happened when you rebased? As described in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228436/failed-to-lock-refs-heads-master

Comment: @SketchyCoder get the same error on the step 4 of that answer ```git push origin master:master```

Comment: Interesting! It might also help to re-add the remote url (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656619/git-and-nasty-error-cannot-lock-existing-info-refs-fatal) but as Edward posted Bitbucket should know the answer.

Comment: I have given that a go. Get the same error.

Comment: Does the file `/data/c01/n08/p/vp0664/data/d-41/r-27032041/refs/heads/master.lock` existing in your git server?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this problem is not with your computer, it is with the server.  This error message is actually coming from your Git server (note the prefix `remote` to the message, this indicates that the error originates on the server.)

If this was your own server with its own Git installation, I would advise you to make sure that there is no long-running Git process doing work and - if there wasn't - removing the lock file it's referring to since a process had indeed crashed.

Since you're running Bitbucket, however, it's probably best to ask them for support instead of changing things on the server directly.